# prodcution環境で特定のjsファイル(datetimepicker)が読み込まれない

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

現在rails 5.06で開発をしており、datetimepickerに必要なファイルをassets/javascript配下とassets/css配下に配置し、application.html.hamlで下記のように読み込んでおります。

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
```

local環境では普通に動くのですがproduction環境だと下記のようなエラーが出てきます。

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) jquery.datetimepicker.js 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) jquery.datetimepicker.full.js 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)  jquery.datetimepicker.css
```

以前別のjqueryファイルを読み込もうとした時も同じような現象になったのでdatetimepickerが原因ではないと思うのですがご存知の方がおりましたらお教え頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: ＞下記のように読み込んでいます
が抜けてしまっておりました。申し訳ございません。

<script type="text/javascript"　src="/assets/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
 
<script src="/assets/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>

Answer (score 0):

コンパイルされていない&パスの指定方法が問題だったぽいです。

コンパイルするように指示をして

**config/initialzers/assets.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.datetimepicker.full.js )
```

下記のようにasset_pathで呼び出してあげることで解決しました！

**application.html.haml**

```
#{asset_path 'jquery.datetimepicker.js'}
```